# can't color cluster with R

Tags: r

I have this matrix in R :

```
         V1        V2     V3     V4     V5     V6     V7
[1,]   0.00    212.86 217.82 209.23 210.06 214.49 186.01
[2,] 199.59      0.00 198.07 201.32 200.82 198.94 188.41
[3,] 200.30    200.85   0.00 198.82 198.43 198.52 185.04
[4,] 198.74    203.82 199.70   0.00 201.23 199.99 191.83
[5,] 199.40    203.14 199.09 202.36   0.00 200.28 192.27
[6,] 199.65 201681.00 198.86 199.21 199.29   0.00 185.71
[7,] 198.71    202.35 198.74 201.45 200.52 198.77   0.00
```

and I want to run it with the pam algorithm in library(cluster) using clustering result as color with the function 'clusplot'.

```
data=read.table('data')
library(cluster)
x= pam(data,2)
clusplot(x, col= x$clustering)
```

but I got this error :

```
Error in clusplot.default ( x$data , x$clustering, diss = FALSE, main = main :
   argument 5 corresponds to several formal arguments
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: try `clusplot(x, color=TRUE)`

Comment: Only the circle around the data are colored; not the data :(

Comment: Inspect all the arguments. See `?clustplot.default` or [here](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/cluster/clusplot.default).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the way `clusplot` is written you can not determine what `col` values are passed to `plot` or `points` directly. The error you are getting is due to partial matching creating ambiguity in trying to do this.

Instead, use the `col.p` parameter to colour the points.

```
clusplot(x, col.p=c("red","blue")[x$cluster])
```